# Can I make Firefox save video snapshots as PNG instead of JPEG?

Tags: firefox

I noticed that when I right-click a video (that is, an HTML5 `<video>` tag), the context menu has an option to take a snapshot of the current frame.

However it's only giving me the option of saving it as a .jpg. Is it possible to save it in a lossless format like PNG instead?

Comment: when i read your question it wasn't edited/updated. why exactly would u want to do this? what is the problem with jpg? or even downloading the jpg and converting it to png.

Comment: Sickest: your comments don't help either. His question is clear and right to the point.